# vb.net, How to get datagridview last cell row and column index

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have create a datagridview in vb.net with several fields, and Input data from keyboard to fill-up the fields,

Now I Want to know How the last cell index (row and column) for storing data from a particular location of this datagridview. Please tell me what to do for store last location cell index (Row and Column) of datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get the last cell's value:

```
        Dim CellValue As String
        With DataGridView1
          CellValue = .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(.ColumnCount - 1).Value
        End With
```

If the last row is empty then use:

```
        Dim CellValue As String
        With DataGridView1
          CellValue = .Rows(.RowCount - 2).Cells(.ColumnCount - 2).Value
        End With
```

Comment: CellValue does not hold any string value??

Comment: You want to read last cell value right? Isn't what you asked for?

Comment: Dim rwo, clm, i, j, eror As Integer
        rwo = DataGridView1.RowCount.ToString
        rwo = rwo - 2
        clm = DataGridView1.ColumnCount.ToString
        clm = clm - 2
        eror = 0
        DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
        Dim sa As String
        For i = 0 To rwo
            For j = 0 To clm
                DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Selected = True

Comment: Adhir ch Mondal, do you mean to get current row and current column? or you want to know which last cell that has data (here you must know to distinguish cell whether it has data or no data, normally without data, the value is nothing) ?